# Autoloading invalid javascript files

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a script which autoloads javascript files based on the users location. Like any other loaders, I create a `<script>` element, set it's `src` attribute and add it to `<head>`. I then listen for `onload` and `onreadystatechanged` etc. events, then check for the presence of a value exposed by the file. This works.

The problem is, when supplied with an invalid cross origin url "http://fail_on_purpose", my ISP returns HTML (directing the browser to reload with a different address). I can catch this in the `onload` event, but it's too late. The HTML has already been injected on the page within the `<script>` tags. This then causes the browser (firefox at least) to issue a `SyntaxError` exception.

All I can do is remove the offending element from the DOM. But, I don't know if this is going to cause problems in other browsers, so I would prefer to not have the error at all.

What is the best way to check for a valid javascript file then inject it into the page?

Update:

Issuing a HEAD or GET request to check if the file exists/is valid, doesn't work due to the "Cross Origin" protection in the browser. I don't have access to the CDN, so that is an unfixable problem.

Comment: did you try `$.get()` inside try-catch?

Comment: @SumitSahay `$.get()` is jQuery, the question is tagged with `javascript`. Besides, I'm not sure if I can add javascript from an AJAX request.

Comment: The best thing to do is only try to load valid JS files. Otherwise, you could check for it's existence first using AJAX.

Comment: @MikeC, It's the 'google maps api', very valid if you ask me. The problem is when loading from .com in countries where google is blocked. The ISP is sending back invalid data. I'll try out sending a HEAD request and see what that returns.

Comment: @Twifty I didn't say it was invalid, I said it's best if you only try to load scripts you know exist. Given that, test for it's existence using AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

You could send a `HEAD` request and parse response headers to see if the page returns successfully, i.e. not with [redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection), [client error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) or [server error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) response code. Any decently implemented server should set correct response code.

Ideally, you'd also check `content-type` to include `application/javascript`, if the server is set up to set it correctly.

If this matches, you know that the script exists, so you can then proceed with loading it the same as you do now.

Alternatively, you already get these headers with `GET` request, so you could do all that with a single request. But with incorrect request, you'll be waiting for all the payload before determining it's incorrect, which will take up more time and waste data transfer. The latter is something worth considering if you're expecting mobile users, you wouldn't want to waste data plans like that.

Comment: I've just tried sending the HEAD, but now firefox is complaining with "Cross-Origin Request Blocked". Any insight into this while I google it?

Comment: The "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is required in the response (reason: Content-Type is not one of the "simple" ones). See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests

Look at the response in the "Network" tab of the developer console, and check which response headers are set.

Can you maybe serve the google JavaScript file from your own server? (not sure if this is allowed by google and if it works)

Comment: You'll find more info on this if you google CORS. Basically, the server is returning a response which is not allowed to be fetched from your domain. This is a common configuration, it prevents a website to load content from other, possibly malicious, origins (i.e. servers). If you have access to server, you could change the headers it responds with. Otherwise the only solution is to fetch the data through a proxy server, but it can be easily abused if you do not set it up properly. After googling it, there is a service for that: https://crossorigin.me/

Comment: It basically looks like I'm not going to be able to make an AJAX call without running into this CORS problem. Trying circumvent it is out of my scope since I already have a fallback mechanism in place. The real issue is the browser injecting HTML into <script> tags. It's a security issue since the ISP could respond anything.

Comment: That's the reason why I suggested to validate `content-type`. The HTML response will not be of content-type `application/javascript`.

Comment: Non of the events are triggered when doing a HEAD/GET request to another origin. I can only apply a timeout to it which still doesn't tell me if the file exists or not. It only tells me the browser is blocking the response.

Comment: If the cross origin request is blocked, obviously it won't trigger any events, since it failed. You should only process the `HEAD` response headers and see if the content is what you're expecting it to be, e.g. a script in this case. If it is, proceed with your loading logic, otherwise don't do anything.

Comment: There are no response headers to process.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing. Managed to do this just fine. [Here is an example.](https://jsfiddle.net/maremp/88vuf6mL/2/)

Answer (score 0):

As Sumit suggests, you might load the script via an Ajax request, then check it somehow (e.g. because you know that it contains a particular string).

On success, just proceed as you did - append a `<script>` tag to the head or body element with the "src" attribute set. If caching is enabled for the URL, the browser won't do another HTTP request for that.

Using the Ajax-loaded JS code directly (by setting scriptElem.text instead of the "src" attribute) is another option, but not as good, since it is subject to CORS restrictions. See jQuery's DOMEval function, https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js (line 77)

Since you want to load the code from the Google servers, the "src"-attribute version is better.